# .NET & gRPC, how to keep certain connection based on client choice?

Tags: c#, .net, grpc

I have a gRPC remote service (.NET 6) and a desktop client app (.NET6/WinForms).
The remote service needs to work with 3 different SQL databases that are 1:1 clones (same structure, different data).
The client app allows users to choose which database to work with based on simple client combobox selection (only once at first run time).

I want to make it work in a way, where the service will always know that any request coming from client X needs to be processed on database Y (previously selected in the client on initial run).

What would be the best way / practice to achieve this kind of functionality?

Comment: Is this a "best practices" question or an "architecture / design" question?  The former is opinion-based and the latter is not focused enough.

Comment: Architecture / design, mainly.

Comment: I'd make it explicit: introduce a parameter in the service, either in uri (https://..../database1/service) or as one of formal parameters of your service methods.

Comment: That depends on whether the client should have control over which database is used. I didn't get the impression that they should. That's what should inform the design. This question is too broad. Questions about which decision to make are off-topic here.